# Lambda that searches list and increments

Tags: python, lambda

Using a Python `lambda` can you check whether an element exists in another list (of maps) and also increment a variable? I'm attempting to optimise/refactor my code using a lambda but I've gone and confused myself.

Below is my existing code that I want to convert to a lambda. Is it possible to do this using one lambda or will I need to use 2 lambdas? Any advice how can I convert it to a lambda/s?

```
current_orders = auth.get_orders() 
# returns [{'id': 'foo', 'price': 1.99, ...}, ...]

deleted_orders = auth.cancel_orders() 
# returns id's of all cancelled orders [{'id': 'foo'}, {'id': 'bar'}, ...]


# Attempting to convert to lambda
n_deleted = 0
for del_order in deleted_orders:
    for order in current_orders:
        if del_order['id'] == order['id']:
            n_deleted += 1

# lambda
n_deleted = filter(lambda order, n: n += order['id'] in current_orders, deleted_orders)
# end


if n_deleted != len(orders):
    logger.error("Failed to cancel all limit orders")
```

*Note:* I know I can say `if len(deleted_orders) < len(current_orders): logger.error("Failed to delete ALL orders")` but I want to expand my lambda eventually to say `...: logger.error("Failed to delete ORDER with ID: %s")`

Comment: `lambda` is designed for implementing a simple, one line function. If you need more than 1 line to get your function done, use `def` to create a function.

Comment: ideally `lambda` functions should not have side-effects

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `+=` (or assignment of any kind) in a `lambda` at all, and using `filter` for side-effects is a terrible idea (this pattern looks kind of like how `reduce` is used, but it's hard to tell what you're trying to do).

It looks like you're trying to count how many `order['id']` values appear in `current_orders`. You shouldn't use a `lambda` for this at all. To improve efficiency, get the `id`s from out as a `set` and use `set` operations to check if all the `id`s were found in both `list`:

```
from future_builtins import map  # Only on Py2, to get generator based map
from operator import itemgetter


... rest of your code ...

getid = itemgetter('id')
# Creating the `set`s requires a single linear pass, and comparison is
# roughly linear as well; your original code had quadratic performance.
if set(map(getid, current_orders)) != set(map(getid, deleted_orders)):
    logger.error("Failed to cancel all limit orders")
```

If you want to know *which* orders weren't canceled, a slight tweak, replacing the `if` check and `logger` output with:

```
for oid in set(map(getid, current_orders)).difference(map(getid, deleted_orders)):
    logger.error("Failed to cancel order ID %s", oid)
```

If you want the error logs ordered by `oid`, wrap the `set.difference` call in `sorted`, if you want it in the same order returned in `current_orders`, change to:

```
from itertools import filterfalse  # On Py2, it's ifilterfalse

# Could inline deletedids creation in filterfalse if you prefer; frozenset optional
deletedids = frozenset(map(getid, deleted_orders))  
for oid in filterfalse(deletedids.__contains__, map(getid, current_orders)):
    logger.error("Failed cancel order ID %s", oid)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to hack around it but `lambda`s should not mutate, they should return a new result. Also you should not overcomplicate `lambda`s, they are meant for short quick functions such a `key` for a `sort` method

Comment: yes true, but I reckon I could do this in 2 lambdas don't you think? A lambda (a) to search 2 lists of maps for the same 'id' then another( b) to increment a value if `a` returns true/1? Ie, nest lambdas?

Comment: @JakeM: `lambda`s are just limited purpose anonymous functions. They can do quite a lot, but they're limited, ugly, and usually the worst way to solve any given problem. You've got a hammer, and you're treating everything like a nail. Solve the problem the correct way, don't keep trying to fit it into a ridiculously convoluted `lambda` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should be using a list comprehension. eg

```
current_order_ids = {order['id'] for order in current_orders}
not_del = [order for order in deleted_orders if order['id'] not in current_order_ids]

for order in not_del:
    logger.error("Failed to delete ORDER with ID: %s", order['id'])
```

Comment: I think you have it backwards, the OP is interested in current orders which were not cancelled, not cancelled orders which were not orders at all (though I suppose both are errors, and the OP's logic detects them equivalently). Also, you could change brackets to parens to skip the listcomp and use a genexpr to avoid the temporary `list` (assuming the results are only iterated once).